# Can I ask other stack overflow members to consider removing their downvote after a post has been deleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, down-votes

I could have modifications ready for a specific question that was downvoted.
I felt like the best thing to do was to delete the post first.

Is it possible to flag for moderator attention after you deleted the post ?

Comment: Could you clarify the question a little? As it stands, I'm not sure why you'd want downvotes removed from a deleted post (most users can't see deleted posts anyway), and what use are modifications to a deleted post?, and ...it's a little confusing.

Comment: Mi Michael. You can undelte after modifying the post. (Or just post the question again). No one likes being downvoted. This is the reason mostly.

Answer (score 9):

Just make the modifications to your question, if they're sufficient, then you'll probably get some up votes. Additionally, if anyone commented following their down vote, leaving a comment will let them know that you've revised the question, which is now a candidate for reconsideration.

It's better to just spend some time drafting your questions, revise it a few times, *then* post it. A great trick I use is to read my posts out loud (quietly, as to not confirm any suspicions that I've truly lost it) to myself to ensure it reads well.

Can you ask for reconsideration? Yes, but only if they've made it possible. We *encourage* constructive comments when down votes are given, but we don't require them - voting should be private for those that don't want to otherwise engage beyond voting.

Comment: I would like to modify this question and other's later. Can I suspend my question untill I do, as to prevent further downvotes ?

Comment: @HCP Why don't you just ask a good question in the first place, instead of asking a bad question and editing it to be good?

Comment: @Doorknob Is is a matter of opinion isn't it ? Doorknob. Why not just provide an answer to the question instead of downvoting me ?

Comment: @HCP Really? "Questions should be good" is an *opinion*?!

Comment: @Doorknob if a question is good is an opinion

Comment: @HCP Could you give an example of a question you want to "suspend"? I'm pretty sure that if it's getting a lot of downvotes, there's a reason, and not just an opinion.

Comment: @Doorknob Yes the question of wanting to suspend questions came from a question I asked on a different stackexchange site that I wanted to work on. as it received two downvoted.

Comment: @HCP So... could you post a link to it?

Comment: @HCP Do you have a link anyway? Some users can see deleted posts.

Comment: @Doorknob sorry i need to go